# How to get file with ftp command knowing only a part of the name?

Tags: ftp, filenames

how do I get with the ftp command to a file of which I know only the first and the last part of the name?

i try to do

```
get $first*$last
```

but it doesn't work.

many thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

use `mget` instead

get retrieves one file, by exact match, mget retrieves multiple by patter match.